# Emulator for Archos 7 tablet?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am working on an app for specifically Archos 7 tab.Could someone tell me how to get an emulator for that device.I have tried with some other emulators but didnt work quite well.
So if someone could help..?Plz

Answer (score 0):

You should googled Archos 7 tab and learn its properties (screen resolution, Android version etc...). And then go Eclipse -> Window -> AVD Manager -> New and customize your new Emulator.

You can specify its screen resolution, Android version, hardware properties (click new button that on hardware part)

Comment: An Archos 7 Tablet would be considered `large` and `ldpi`. Use that for the hardware properties.

Comment: I have managed to get the resolution and all other properties of the device ..But when i run my app on that the app is displayed but it is not on fullscreen..and most of the part of the layout is not seen...